# Glassfish eclipselink HashSet error

Tags: glassfish, eclipselink, hashset

I am using glassfish and JPA (eclipselink tenant)

In OneToOneMapping on the Map insertableField many objects are added in map maintaining one instance per tenant.
**But after some time using the system** the HashSet insertableField in OneToOneMapping presents its size zero and the internal table contains a value look image two, and when the system will run insertableFields.contains method the field is not localized and thus is not added in the query causing the following error.

See the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Bic.png "HashSet error"

The error, any suggestion?

Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value 
in column "id_user" violates not-null constraint
Detalhe: Failing row contains (null, 0, 1).

INSERT INTO "tenant".cfguser (column1, 
column2) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [1, 0]

Comment: The value is obviously null. You should add some code to the question to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it is not so obvious .
Still fails to simulate this error with unit testing, it only happens after
time of use of the system.
But the solution to the issue is how the class java.util.HashSet
allows internally have "size" zero and value in the internal map see the image. Tanks.